# An uncountable set of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $Z$ be a set of sequence.$\forall \{a_n\}, \exists \{b_n\} \in Z$, such that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$. Prove that $Z$ is uncountable.

We are asked to prove this using the Cantor's Diagonal Argument, but I don't see how it works. Any other approaches are acceptable as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is true? The set of sequences $\{(n^m)_n|m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ satisfies this requirement, since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^m}{n^{m+1}} = 0$. Even the empty set works, btw.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. It turns out that $\{a_n\} $ can be any sequence instead of any sequence $\in Z$. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the set $Z$ is defined as the set of all sequences of integers $\{a_n\}$ such that there is a sequence of integers $\{b_n\]$ with $a_n/b_n\to0$. Otherwise the question makes very little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Z$ were countable, we could label its elements $\{z_n^1\}, \{z_n^2\}, \ldots$ (using superscripts because subscripts are taken already). Define a new sequence $\{a_n\}$ by $$a_n = \max\limits_{i,j \leq n}z^i_j.$$

Note that for all $m \geq n$, we have $a_m \geq z^n_m$, so $a_m/z^n_m \geq 1$, so we cannot have $a_m/z^n_m\to 0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If **all** you know about the set $Z$ is the statement $$\forall \{a_n\}\in Z \exists \{b_n\}\in Z : \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0,$$

then it is not possible to prove that $Z$ is uncountable. The set $\{\}$ (i.e., the empty set) satisfies the above condition, and is very much countable. Since you cannot prove that $Z$ is not the empty set, you also cannot prove that $Z$ is not countable.

Comment: Yes you are right, I've already corrected the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $(z_n)_n$ be a sequence of all sequences in $Z$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Then consider the following sequence $a_n$ defined by the following equation.
$$a_n = z_{\operatorname{ord}_2(n)+1}[n]$$
This sequence infinitely often coincides with every element in $(z_n)_n$.

There needs to be a sequence $(b_n)_n \in Z$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$. This sequence $(b_n)_n\in Z$ has to be $z_m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$, but $(a_n)_n$ is equal to $z_m$ infinitely often at positions $2^{m-1}\mathbb{N}$. so $\big(\frac{a_n}{b_n}\big)$ can't converge to $0$ given that a subsequence of $\big(\frac{a_n}{b_n}\big)$ converges to $1$.

This contradiction shows that the assumption that $Z$ is countable is false.

Comment: It's correct. Thanks!

Comment: @bvbarsenal It is good practice to upvote correct answers to your questions, to thank people for their time and effort.

Comment: Yes I voted, but the system told me that votes cast by those less than 15 reputation do not change the publicly displayed post score. I will vote for your answer again when I have enough reputation.